# Prove   $1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a < \frac{(n+1)^{(a+1)}-1}{a+1} $ for any $a >0$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Prove for any $a >0$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}  $

$$1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a < \frac{(n+1)^{(a+1)}-1}{a+1}$$

Also for $a \in (-1,0)$ the above inequality is reversed.

For $n=1, 2^{(a+1)}-1 > (a+1)$ is true

Let us assume the result is true for $n=m$, i.e.

$$1^a+2^a+\cdots+m^a < \frac{(m+1)^{(a+1)}-1}{a+1}$$

Now

$$1^a+2^a+\cdots+m^a + (m+1)^a < \frac{(m+1)^{(a+1)}-1}{a+1} + (m+1)^a $$

$$ < \frac{(m+1)^a (m+1+a) + (m+1)^a -1}{a+1} $$

I think I am making progress so far, now what?

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: For $n=1, 2^{(a+1)}-1 > a+1$ and assume for $n=m$ and prove for $n=m$ right?

Comment: I mean prove for $n=m+1$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^a \lt \int_{1}^{n+1} x^a \text{ d}x = \frac{(n+1)^{a+1} - 1}{a+1}$$

Comment: Wow!, one liner proof (Genius).  How about $a \in (-1,0)$, any suggestions ?

Comment: @AlexSmith: Your question clearly states $a \gt 0$, but I believe the inequality is reversed when $a \lt 0$ ($x^a$ becomes a decreasing function). Try drawing the graphs and one should be able to see.

Comment: I got it same kind with inequality reversed (I think I understand how to get it)